# GAE sessions disappearing after POST request from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine, session, session-variables

I have a GAE application that uses a session to store something. There is an Android app that works with it, sending requests, the GAE uses the session when responding. Now I'm trying to make a JavaScript client that does the same thing as the Android does. It uses XMLHttpRequest to send Ajax requests (with CORS enabled) to the GAE app. The first request goes through fine, but the second one - where it needs to retrieve an object from thes ession - crashes with a NullPointerException when trying to read from the session.

These two requests were sent by the same page, one on load and one when a button is clicked by the user.

Anyone have any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that as it was a cross-domain Ajax request the cookie with the session ID wasn't saved. To allow that to happen (in Chrome at least) the request needs to have withCredentials set to true. That means that on the server side no wildcard is allowed for Access-Control, and the Access-Control must be set to allow credentials.